# The return type is incorrect

Tags: c++

The type is defined:

```
typedef int (*vlc_media_player_is_playing(libvlc_media_player_t*));
```

The class defines a field with this type. The field is populated with the address of the function from the dll. When you try to call a function, the `int*` pointer is returned instead of `int`. Why is this happening?

Thus, in the pointer are the data correct.

> When you try to dereference the pointer, the program
>   crashes.

I will also add that an example of this type:

```
typedef struct libvlc_instance_t libvlc_instance_t;
typedef libvlc_instance_t(*vlc_create_instance(int, const char* const*));
```

Somehow, too, returns a pointer at once.

```
class Foo
{
...
private:
    vlc_media_player_is_playing*    libvlc_media_player_is_playing = nullptr;
...
public:
    Foo()
    {
        libvlc_media_player_is_playing = (vlc_media_player_is_playing*)GetSomeAddress("SomeFuncName");
    }

    void call()
    {
        // but this is not `int`
        int result = libvlc_media_player_is_playing(player_ptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling that function?

Comment: @KerrekSB: question updated

Comment: `libvlc_media_player_is_playing` is a pointer isn't it?

Comment: @Raindrop7: yeah, this is pointer to function

Comment: @Yami: Then what is `vlc_media_player_is_playing*`?

Comment: @MooingDuck: is declared type for function

Comment: @MooingDuck: Yes the OP uses a pointer to a pointer to a function which he shouldn't do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vlc_media_player_is_playing` is an alias to a pointer to a function that returns an integer and takes a pointer to `libvlc_media_player_t` struct.

So any usage of this type is considered to be a pointer to function eg:

```
vlc_media_player_is_playing myFunc = SomeFuncReturningIntTakingVlc;
```

To call the function through the pointer eg:

```
int ret = (*myFunc)(libvlc_media_player_tParam);
```

But you created a pointer to a pointer to function here:

```
 vlc_media_player_is_playing* libvlc_media_player_is_playing = nullptr;
```

So remove the pointer operator above to make it look like:

```
vlc_media_player_is_playing libvlc_media_player_is_playing = nullptr;
```

And to call the function later in your function `call`:

```
int result = (*libvlc_media_player_is_playing)(player_ptr);
```